# how to populate multiple line textbox in crm using plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2013

Hey I would like to know what is the way to populate multiple line field by **plugin**, I need to start a new line in the multiple line field.
my code is:

```
 foreach (Entity ent in allMyEnts.Entities)
          {            
                 //base_filesName is the multiple field need to be filled 
                 //inside my loop                                                  
             entityHoldsMultipleLineField.base_filesName =ent.base_name;
                                       }
```

Or should I create an Array and populate my field with a loop ?
What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a bug in your code with `Entity ent` because you then refer to `ent.base_name` - this won't work because you are calling the object as an early-bound entity but you are casting it as late-bound in the `foreach` statement. I'm going to assume you intended to use late-bound for my answer (you can change this to early-bound, as needed.

A multi-line textbox is still a `string` as far as Dynamics and .NET are concerned. You can use the `StringBuilder` class to easily create a multi-line string and then add that the resultant `string` (via `.ToString()`) to the proper field.

```
var multiLineStringResult = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Entity ent in allMyEnts.Entities)
{
    //base_filesName is the multiple field need to be filled 
    //inside my loop                                                  
     multiLineStringResult.AppendLine(ent.GetAttributeValue<string>("base_name"));
}

entityHoldsMultipleLineField["base_filesName"] = multiLineStringResult.ToString();
```

Comment: you are right no special attrs to crm multiline, finally I used the simple:  {entityHoldsMultipleLineField.base_filesName =ent.base_name + Environment.NewLine;} and that's all :)